# Error: An API error occurred: invalid_auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api

Hi I'm writing my slack bot, and I want after select, change prev message to a new variat, this is my action which is triggerd after select:

```
slackInteractions.action({ type: "static_select" }, (payload, res) => {
  console.log(payload);
  web.chat
    .update({
      token: slackSigningSecret,
      channel: payload.container.channel_id,
      ts: payload.container.message_ts,
      as_user: true,
      text: "Hello World"
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

And I got error:

```
Error: An API error occurred: invalid_auth
    at Object.platformErrorFromResult (/home/codex/Documents/dan-bot/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/errors.js:50:33)
    at WebClient.apiCall (/home/codex/Documents/dan-bot/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/WebClient.js:485:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',
  data: { ok: false, error: 'invalid_auth', response_metadata: {} }
}
```

This is payload:

```
{
  type: 'block_actions',
  team: { id: '//', domain: '*** },
  user: {
    id: 'U010Q9X59QT',
    username: '**',
    name: '***',
    team_id: '//'
  },
  api_app_id: '///',
  token: '***',
  container: {
    type: 'message',
    message_ts: '1585662258.008100',
    channel_id: '****',
    is_ephemeral: true
  },
  trigger_id: '1038328652789.1035324920279.b84d3403b8e44ab0cd53c997ba8b4c72',
  channel: { id: '***', name: 'directmessage' },
  response_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/actions/T01119JT287/1040413692903/6TWTQqXhcp453TPREb7uRcPn',
  actions: [
    {
      type: 'static_select',
      action_id: 'wkR',
      block_id: 'LM9',
      selected_option: [Object],
      placeholder: [Object],
      action_ts: '1585662260.040519'
    }
  ]
}
```

As token I use my main slack token, using this I'm trying to change block where I seelcted variant to another block, at the moment trying to change as string "Hello world"
Thanks in forward!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Looking back at their documentation for [chat.update](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update#arg_token), the token should be the access token you see on the Oauth & Permissions tab and it starts with `xoxb` or `xoxp`. Please check more about their Oauth documentation here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2

Comment: I miscopied my token - thanks for the xoxb bit!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and eventually found out it was caused by passing the wrong token (copy-paste issues).

What helped me debug it:

1. Check the structure of the token. Most modern tokens start with `xoxb-` and have a length of 56 characters
2. Test that the token works before wrapping it in code, using e.g. [Slack's auth test API](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test/test)